# Run Startup Disk Creator as Root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bootable-media

I am having issues with permissions while trying to create a startup disk using Startup Disk Creator. I was able to accomplish this task by using UNetBootin but the disk it creates is failing to boot. Is there a way to start Startup Disk Creator from terminal as root?

I've tried searching for it using by entering 'start' or 'startup' and entering tab tab but with no luck. I can however find it from search from the dash home. What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command for the startup disk creator is `usb-creator-gtk`. Run it as root with `gksudo usb-creator-gtk`.

In the future, you may find the `apropos` command useful. It allows you to find appropriate commands.

In this instance, `apropos startup` gave me:

```
default.pa (5)       - PulseAudio Sound Server Startup Script
genisoimagerc (5)    - startup configuration file for genisoimage
start-pulseaudio-kde (1) - PulseAudio Sound Server KDE Startup Script
start-pulseaudio-x11 (1) - PulseAudio Sound Server X11 Startup Script
startup (7)          - event signalling system startup
usb-creator-gtk (8)  - Ubuntu startup disk creation tool for Gtk+
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to an Ubuntu machine at the moment and "Startup Disk Creator" seems to be an Ubuntu app. In any case, what you can do is run `ps` to list running processes before and after running the program:

1. List currently running processes owned by your user and save to a file

   ```
   ps xo user,command | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > file1
   ```
2. Open "Startup Disk Creator" from the menu and then run the above command again, saving the output to another file

   ```
   ps xo user,command | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > file2
   ```
3. Now compare the two files, there should only be one difference, "Startup Disk Creator"

   ```
   diff file1 file2
   ```
4. That's it, you now know the actual command used to launch the program and can launch it as root.

You might also be interested in the various other programs that can help you build bootable USBs. Here are some of my favorites:

- [Live USB multiboot](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/)
- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

A great source of information for this kind of thing is the [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) website.